# Embedding Java Applet into Google Sites Error

Tags: java, netbeans, applet, embed, google-sites

Normally I don't ask questions but I've been stuck on this for three days now and can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

I've created a small program in netbeans that's been very useful, it runs fine in netbeans and works the way it's supposed to. However I can't seem to get it to embed properly into a Google site. I've searched everywhere but have been mainly following this tutorial: https://sites.google.com/site/ruslancray/lab/projects/how-to-embed-java-applet-onto-your-google-site

It seems like it should work however I keep getting the same error: ClassFormatError Incompatible magic value 1011373133. I've tried just about everything but it always comes back to that same error. I also tried opening the class file in a hex editor and it does indeed have CA FE BA BE as the first four bytes.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a java program on my website but , I think you can deploy java Web application on the Google Sites with Appengine.

https://cloud.google.com/products/app-engine/

I think it's possible with this.